# Circular View Path on trying to return view from Controller in Springboot app

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is a Spring Initialzr project downloaded online at Spring website. I am using a normal `@Controller` and returning a String, which is supposed to return the view name. I have `dog.html` inside the location `src/main/resources/templates/`.
The Controller and html files are posted below.

dog.html  below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
     <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>  
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` 
     </head>
    <body>
    <p> ggg</p>
     <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${dogBreed.breedName} + '!'" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

ViewController below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Disney")
public class ViewController {

    @Autowired
    BreedService breedService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{breedName}")
    public String getDogsbyBreedName(@PathVariable("breedName") String breedName, Model model) {

        //call a method which returns the Object Breed.

        // store this returned Object "breed" and return it as an html view to display as Graphical content.
        BreedMaster breed = breedService.getAllDogsByBreedName(breedName);
        model.addAttribute("dogBreed",breed);
        return "dog";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/viewtest")
    public String sampleTest(){


        return "sample";
    }

}
```

sample.html below

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> sample html</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The method `breedService.getAllDogsByBreedName(breedName)` returns the list of dogs by breed name which i want to send it to the HTML `dog.html`. but here note that even for url `/viewtest` its not reutrning `sample.html` throwing error. Meaning i cant reach `dog.html` as well as `sample.html` and have never changed any springboot autoconfiguration. Need help on this very badly, i think its a silly mistake anyone please pint it out, Thank you.

the error message which i get on invoking `/viewtest` is as follows:
[image: While Returning sample.html from controller method]

the error message which i get on invoking `/{breedName}` is as follows:
Note that the reutrning String "dog" is not similar to the entered "/{breedName}" which is "Labrador"
[image: While Returning dog.html from controller method]

Answer (score 0):

Try to unchecked the spring-security in spring boot and re-check the database configuration( attribute in application.properties, configuration class).

Comment: spring.h2.console.enabled: true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL: debug
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:~/DisneyDB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
server.port: 8384


I have only these in my application.yml file

Comment: Copy the exception from console when you try to access the URL but can't open that page.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the problem, and solution for it.
I am using Thymeleaf template engine so had made use of it in my dog.html but had added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

having version no 3.0.1 but later changed the version number to 1.2.1.RELEASE which worked. After this I can return all the html files from `@Controller` class methods. Didn't know how it affected even simple html though, and also why it was throwing `Circular view path` error.